# Generating sets and independent subsets in abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

**Definition.** A set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of non zero elements in an Abelian group is *independent* if, whenever there are integers $m_1,...,m_r$ with $m_1 x_1 + \cdots + m_r x_r = 0$, then each $m_i x_i$ is zero. (*Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, 4th edition, by Rotman, Springer-Verlag, p.127.)

I want to know:

> In a finite Abelian group, is a minimal generating set necessarily an independent set?

I have tried to prove it but I have failed. Perhaps if the group is primary (a p-group for some prime p)?

> More precisely, suppose I have a set that generates G. By removing elements from the set one at a time, can I get an independent set which still generates G?

Answer (score 0):

This is not always the case not even for $p$-groups. 
Take the direct sum of a cyclic group of order $p$ and one of order $p^2$. 
Let them be generated by $g$ and $h$ respectively. This would be an independent generating set. But now consider $g+h$ and $h$. This is still minimal (of course, as the group is not cyclic), yet not independent .

It is of course true for direct sums of groups of order $p$ a prime (the notion of independence coincides with linear independent over the field with $p$ elements, and this is just linear algebra).

It remains  true for direct sums of groups of order $p^k$ a prime power. 
(This is not very hard to see.)

And, I believe, but did not fully think it through that these are all the finite abelian groups for which it is true.

Comment: Actually a cyclic group of ord $pq$ would be another example where it is true. (I refrain from saying that now it should be complete. If/when I actually figure out the complete list I'll update this.)